# Single SQL query to select all customers together with all the orders belonging to each of the customer?

Tags: sql-server, c#

I'm learning SQL and suddenly I have this question in my mind. Given that I have .NET classes representing customers and orders like this:

```
public class ListCustomers
{
    public List<Customers> MyBigList {get; set;}
    public ListCustomers()
    {
        // some code to query database
    }
}

public class Customers
{
    public int CustomerID {get; set;}
    public String CustomerName {get; set;}
    public String CustomerEmail {get; set;}
    public String CustomerPhone {get; set;}
    public List<Orders> CustomerOrders {get; set;}
}

public class Orders
{
    public int OrderID {get; set;}
    public double OrderTotalAmount {get; set;}
    public String BillingAddress {get; set;}
    public String ShippingAddress {get; set;}
}
```

Normally I would select all the customers first and then in my code I would have a foreach loop to select orders to fill each of the `List<Orders> CustomerOrders` property.

However this requires multiple trip to SQL Server and I'm wondering if there is any way to fill the whole `List<Customers> MyBigList` class using only one trip to SQL? In that case how would the DataSet/DataTable of result look like?

Comment: I would keep them separate.  One query to get the list of customers.  Another query to get the list of orders.  But instead of getting the list of orders for each customer, get the list of all orders for all customers that you need in one pull.  You should be able to pass in a list of customers.

Comment: Have you considered a `JOIN` ?

Comment: Do you use a custom DAO or Entity Framework to access your database? 
Given the data model of your c# classes we cannot establish a link between orders and customers, maybe provide the real database model if you want sql query answers.
As @Lennart said It would include a join or a query returning 2 datasets, then you handle the "join" logic in your code.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this.

Im not sure how your SQL is returned but if you use a

> SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()

One way would be to load all the orders belonging to a customer for every customer that is loaded, however there will be a trip to SQL for each customer to get their orders.

```
public LoadCustomers()
{
    // some code to query database
    // some code to handle the data and add to your list
    while (SQLdta.Read()){
        Customers customer = new Customers();
        customer.CustomerOrders = loadCustomerOrders();
        MyBigList.Add(this);
    }
}
```

Option 2 - Another possible solution would be to create a list of the customers you need orders for and get them all in one pull and match them to their respective customers.
Minimum Two SQL hits...

Option 3 - A little messy in my opinion but may be best suited to your needs.
Create Tow SQL Queries
Execute as one SQL hit.

E.g.

```
SELECT CustomerID,CustomerName,CustomerEmail,CustomerPhone 
FROM Customers 
WHERE (YOUR WHERE STRING GOES HERE);
```

Then do another query for the Orders

```
SELECT OrderID,OrderTotalAmount,BillingAddress,ShippingAddress 
FROM Orders 
WHERE (YOUR ORDERS WHERE STRING GOES HERE) 
AND CustomerID IN ( SELECT CustomerID FROM Customers WHERE (YOUR WHERE STRING GOES HERE));
```

Both will sent to SQL and you will execute your query together returning 2 result tables

So in your Class you may do something like this.

```
//Your SQL query execution code
    
//Reads your Customers First
while (SQLdta.Read())
{
    //Your logic to populate your customers list
}

//Move the reader to the next returned results table and read the orders
while (SQLdta.NextResult())
{
    while (SQLdta.Read())
    {
        //Your logic to populate your orders list
    }
}
```

At this point you will have 2 lists and you may then be able to link the orders to your Customers

If your sticking with a dataset then it works the same except each table in the dataset will be your separate SQL query results.

```
if ((dataSet != null) && (dataSet.Tables != null) && (dataSet.Tables.Count > 0))
{
    foreach (DataTable d in dataSet.Tables)
    {
        //your code to handle each tables data
    }
}
```